# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException problem while trying to deserialize with a model

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, asp.net-core

m trying to deserialize a Json file, using this class as a model:

```
using CsQuery.StringScanner.Patterns;
using Lucene.Net.Support;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test_Api
{
    public class Metric
    {
        public string __name__ { get; set; }
        public string instance { get; set; }
        public string job { get; set; }

    }
    public class Result
    {
        public Metric metric { get; set; }
        public IList<Lucene.Net.Support.Number> value { get; set; }

    }
    public class Data
    {
        public string resultType { get; set; }
        public IList<Result> result { get; set; }

    }
    public class Application
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }

    }
}
```

my Program.cs is:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using QuickType;
namespace Test_Api
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Application> DataG = new List<Application>();
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?query=go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction"))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    DataG = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Application>>(apiResponse);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DataG);
        }

    }
}
```

It keeps giving me this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Test_Api.Application]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

I want to know if there is a standart way to deserialize json things using a specific model, any help would be appreciated, be gentel please, Im a newbie.

**EDIT:**
The Json I want to get the values from is:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "vector",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {
                    "__name__": "process_cpu_seconds_total",
                    "instance": "localhost:9090",
                    "job": "prometheus"
                },
                "value": [
                    1545222126.353,
                    "0.615464"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: you could make use of `dynamic` this way it works. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(apiResponse);` and your DataG should then be a dynamic too

Comment: According to the error, it looks like your `apiResponse` contains  `JSON object` and not array

Comment: Thanks a lot, and if I want to get a specific attribute to show it on my front-end does it work too ?

Comment: @Hadas yes I will edit the post and share the Json file.

Comment: As @Anu said,you need to change `List<Application>` to `Application`.But you would meet another issue by using `Lucene.Net.Support.Number`.Why did you want to use this namespace?Why not use `IList<Object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application>(apiResponse);
```

Your Json returns a single instance of the `Application`, while you were attempting to deserialize the Json as a `List<Application>` as per the code in OP. This was the cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your response to array first

```
Application[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Application[]>(apiResponse,
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});
```

and then you can create list from array i.e

```
List<Application> DataG = new List<Application>();

for(int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    DataG.Add(result[i]);
}
```

now you can use your list